# locating a screen session within multiple desktops

Tags: terminal, desktop, gnu-screen

I've usually got a lot of stuff on the go, including 10 or more `screen` sessions.  I also have a lot of desktops set up.  Sometimes I want to find a particular `screen` session among the many desktops.  In general I only have one connection to a given `screen` session.

Getting the current desktop from a terminal session is readily accomplished with `wmctrl -d`, but the trick is to run that program from the desktop that I'm looking for.  IE connecting to that `screen` session and then doing `wmctrl -d` will list as the current desktop the one that I'm *connecting from*; this is not very informative.

Since I usually have many tabs open in `yakuake` (possibly 10 or more of these at a time), it would be helpful to know which tab of that terminal program the screen session is running in.

`screen` instances that are not running in `yakuake` are usually located in the only tab of a `roxterm` window that's the only terminal window in its desktop.

Ideally I would just give the name of a screen session to get a list of the locations of windows containing connected instances.

It may also be relevant that my window manager is `openbox`.

Is there a way to find the desktop and/or terminal tabs of these screen instances?